# How to deduplicate a table based on more common field value?

Tags: sql, mysql

In my database every entry has a number of IDs (let's call them IdentifierType and IdentifierValue) as well a value (let's call it GuidValue.) Each set of Ids should point to one GuidValue. However it so happens that some Ids are duplicates and there is a clear algorithm for finding them (for simplicity let's say they are duplicates if they have the same UpCase value.) Some of those will correctly feature the same GuidValue, but others (a maximum of 1) will not. How do I set the offending values to correct GuidValue?
(note that while IdentifierType and IdentifierValue are duplicates for this purpose, they aren't for others, so I can not simply delete all duplicates)

the query

```
SELECT IdentifierType, upper(IdentifierValue), count(distinct GuidValue)
FROM `Identifier`
where IdentifierType = "specific type"
group by upper(IdentifierValue), IdentifierType
having count(distinct GuidValue) > 1
```

finds all the duplicates.
similarly

```
Select a.*
from Identifier as a
join
   (SELECT IdentifierType, upper(IdentifierValue) as uic, count(distinct GuidValue)
    FROM `Identifier`
    where IdentifierType = "specific type"
    group by upper(IdentifierValue), IdentifierType
    having count(distinct GuidValue) > 1) as b
  on a.IdentifierValue = b.uic and b.IdentifierType = b.IdentifierType
```

will find all GuidValues.
If I were fixing this manually, I would just change whichiver GuidValue is the least common. but I'm not sure how to automate this.

Sample data:

| IdentifierType | IdentifierValue | GuidValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| other type | A | 11 |
| specific type | A | 21 |
| specific type | a | 22 |
| specific type | ABC | 31 |
| specific type | ABc | 31 |
| specific type | Abc | 32 |

We want both a and A to point to 21, and all of ABC, ABc, and Abc to point to 31. A solution that makes a and A point to 22 is undesirable, but acceptable since it's unclear which one is the majority.

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You have rows with the same identifyer type and identifier value. These are supposed to have all different GUID values, but sometinmes it happens that two or more rows for the same identifyer type and identifier value have the same GUID value. And now you want to do what? Delete existing rows? Or change identifyier types or identifier values or GUID values? If you want an update, to what other value do you want this? Please edit your request and add sample data (some rows with the duplicate problem before the operation and the result rows after the operation).